# Detecting statically whether a linq expression is null

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

My problem is that I want to check for any given Linq Expression, say whether it is as an **expression** equal to the expression constant null (i.e. Expression.Constant(null)), *without compiling it*. However, what I don't want to do is compare whether the **value** of the expressions is null. This is a purely syntactic check. For example, this expression would not work:

`Expression.Equal(Expression.Constant(null), a)` for expression a

Since

```
Expression.Equal(Expression.Constant(null), 
           Expression.Conditional(
                  Expression.Constant(false),
                  Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(3), typeof(object)),
                  Expression.Constant(null)))
```

would evaluate to true, which is not what I'm looking for.

I want to do it ideally with something like `a.IsNullExpr`. However, the naïve solution of doing

```
public static bool IsNullExpr(Expressions a) { return a == Expression.Constant(null); }
```

doesn't seem to work, presumably because the equality operator for linq expressions is done based on the object address (or something similar) (*I think*, at the very least `Expression.Constant(null) == Expression.Constant(null)` evaluates to false).

Is there a very simple way of solving this problem which I've overlooked?

Comment: _Crucially, I don't want to do this within linq with something like:_, why?

Comment: *without compiling it* But if you want to return a `bool` the expression must be evaluated. I think what you want is convert an expression to an expression that returns a boolean (aka a predicate).

Comment: Two reasons: If we have a linqExpression which is type String, but evaluates to null (perhaps through a method call) but which isn't a constant, this is different as an expression to the an expression with a constant null. I want a solution which rules that out. (I need the expression itself to be a constant null, not any old expression which evaluates to the value null). An analogy might be that (3+4) and 7 evaluate to the same value, but are different expressions. Reason two is that the expression a might be potentially very slow, and I don't want to have to run it.

Comment: What about an expression of the form `(string)null` or `(string)(object)null`?  Both are null constants, but the constants are buried within `Convert` expressions.  What about `Expression.Default(typeof(string))`?  That's effectively a null constant, but it's not a `ConstantExpression`.  Do you want to detect these cases?

Comment: @MikeStrobel For my case, I would not consider the convert expression a null constant (My problem was dealing with non converted nulls in a typed expression (a different expression library, not linq's) ! I naively thought the program I was using would insert the conversions!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do it like this:

```
Expression exp = Expression.Constant(null);
bool isNull = exp is ConstantExpression && ((ConstantExpression)exp).Value == null;
```